# How amount of data and code affects fork() performance in Perl?

Tags: perl, fork

What is overhead of `fork()` in Perl in regard to Perl's own data structures? Does 1) size of code (syntax tree) and 2) amount of data in variables/references affect amount of time spent on forking?

Answer (score 5):

Not a Perl question, since `fork` is a system call. It does not matter whether that process is Perl or not, it always does the same things. It does not care about the partical internals of a process, only the total memory size has an effect.

Modern operating systems such as Linux implement [COW](http://enwp.org/Copy-on-write), so `fork` usually returns very quickly, nearly the same for each process.

Comment: `fork` in Perl is function, which in turn will call `fork` syscall. Nothing stops Perl from having some pre-/post- process around it, like, for example, it does with another system facility, like signals.

Comment: And that pre-/postprocessing is… [nothing relevant, really](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/HEAD:/pp_sys.c#l4026).

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is, as others have said, that the amount of code/data has no bearing on `fork()` performance beyond what is generically implied by your system's implementation.

However, perl itself will flush open filehandles before calling fork, [per the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html).  So, yes, the number of open perl filehandles has some bearing on fork() performance.

(Threaded perl builds will also throw an internal mutex protecting memory allocation, at least under 5.16 on my system.  Small, internal synchronization like that will likely vary from system to system and from perl version to perl version.)

Answer (score 3):

Forking creates a separate copy of the entire process -- code and data -- everything except the I/O handles. So anything that increases the memory footprint of your program will (at the margin) make the fork operation take longer.

For programs that process large amounts of data and multiple child processes, one thing to consider is keeping the footprint of the parent process as small as possible and loading data after the child processes have started.

Comment: I/O handles are held open by both processes after a `fork()`.

Answer (score 1):

`fork` uses no memory in of itself. The memory pages of the parent process are shared with the child process until the child tries to write to a shared page, at which point a copy of the page is made so that each process has its own a copy of the page.

If code and read-only data is separated from writable data, that results in many pages that will always be shared.

However, there is no separation of code and data in Perl. Not only are opcodes created in the same memory pool as data, opcodes have writeable components! This means a forked child will often eventually end up being mostly unshared, I imagine.

To know for sure, you'll have to dig out `ps` while your processes are running.